# Firefox extension: How update vanilla context menu entries?

Tags: firefox-addon, contextmenu

I would like to change a given existing vanilla firefox context menu entry.
For example: When right-clicking an image instead of seeing "Copy Image" one should see "Image Copy" in the future. (which would be an update of the title like:

browser.contextMenus.update({
id: "copy-image",
title: "Image Copy"
});

sadly I couldn't find any information about the id's of vanilla firefox context menu entries. I have the supposition that the id's are only for handling selfmade context menu entries. Can someone give me a hint where I can find the documentation since https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/78/menus.html doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/overrideContext

Comment: Thanks. But this forces me to rebuild the entire menu, doesn't it?

Comment: Looks like it... may be worth experimenting with though since, I don't see a cleaner solution atm.  `contextMenus.update` only applies to extension-created context menu items